# how to cmpound the regression model with time series?

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models

how do combination of regression model and time series for better predictive? for prediction of consumation of energy data. previously just use linear regression model for consumation energy but it is not enough for prediction

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is very broad and it is not clear what is your problem about, I'll try to provide just a couple of starting points for methods involving regression and time series.

If you are using univariate time series - that is, you are trying to predict future consumption of energy from data on previous consumption -, [auto-regresive moving-average models](http://Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average%20model) (ARMA) perform regression analysis with future value as response and previous values as predictors.

If you are doing regression analysis to predict consumption with other variables as predictors and you want to combine this method with time series analysis, you can look for [multivariate time series analysis](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc45.htm). The equivalent of ARMA for multivariate series is ARMAV, where we try to predict future values of a set of variables using their previous values.

Comment: yes i want to regression analysis to predict consumption with other variables as predictors and  want to combine this method with time series analysis. I want to combine the series models with self-correlation with regression models.

Comment: Then you can use the link above for multivariate time series or search this site: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multivariate+time+series+regression

Comment: My research field is energy monitorng and targeting.Energy performance is typically modeled with linear regression and presented for interpretation using cumulative sum of residuals (CUSUM) charts.we must disambiguate multiple known changes, detect unknown changes and, most importantly, diagnose and act on changes to energy performance.But modeling of linear regression and cusum plot is not enough in this area. cusum's model does not work well to identify complicated and complex changes and CUSUM plots aren’t very informative in distinguishing overlapping changes,

Comment: even if changes don’t obscure each other. For example, if consumption is shifted from one period to another (e.g. weekday to weekend), or if a driver-related efficiency change is offset by a coincident change to baseload, a CUSUM chart will show only the net difference.What is better statistics modeling than regression can I use to predict energy use using different variables? And what control charts are more suitable than cusum for energy monitoring and the correct identification of energy fluctuations?